# Merge two objects in php

Tags: php, object

I use an API that returns me to an email address given an array like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [status] => OK
    [contact] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 0000000
            [email] => toto@free.fr
            [last_activity] => 1362131446
            [last_update] => 0
            [created_at] => 1356617740
            [sent] => 5
            [open] => 1
            [click] => 1
            [spam] => 0
            [bounce] => 0
            [blocked] => 0
            [queued] => 0
        )
[lists] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [active] => 1
                    [unsub] => 1
                    [unsub_at] => 1363078528
                )

        )

)
```

how to merge info [contact] with [lists] [0] in a single object?

Thank you for your help

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
$info = yourstuff;
$arrContact = (array) $info->contact;
$arrList = (array) $info->lists[0];
$merged = array_merge($arrContact, $arrList);
var_dump($merged, 'have fun');
```

Quite trivial ;)

Comment: Better solution for the question

Answer (score 11):

```
 <?php
$a = new stdClass;
$a->name = 'Anthony';

$b = new stdClass;
$b->location = 'UK';

$c = (object)array_merge((array)$a, (array)$b);

var_dump($c);

/*
    object(stdClass)#3 (2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(7) "Anthony"
      ["location"]=>
      string(2) "UK"
    }
*/
```

Comment: I like the idea of casting it to an object again. Too bad I didn't thought of that before.

Comment: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: @MaxLeps That's why he used casting before use. Check this line: `$c = (object)array_merge((array)$a, (array)$b);` This answer seems to be perfect for the question. Please mark it as best answer.

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
foreach ($info->lists[0] as $key => $value {
  $info->contact->$key = $value;
}
```

Avoids casting back and forth between arrays and objects

Comment: (there's a typo here)